# Python: Errors don`t stop script

Tags: python, parsing, error-handling

I wrote a python-daemon that parses some web pages. But sometimes there are errors due to the fact that some of the pages are not compatible with the parser.

Actually the question: how to make the script when errors did not stop, but just continued to work? And if possible, record all the errors in the log file.

Thanks.

**Part of my code:**

```
# row - array of links
for row in result:
    page_html = getPage(row['url'])
    self.page_data = row

    if page_html != False:
        self.deletePageFromIndex(row['id'])
        continue

    parser.mainlink = row['url']
    parser.feed(page_html)

    links = parser.links # get links from page
    words = wordParser(page_html); # words from page

    # insert data to DB
    self.insertWords(words)
    self.insertLinks(links)

    # print row['url'] + ' parsed. sleep... '

    self.markAsIndexed(row['id'])
    sleep(uniform(1, 3)) # sleep script
```

Comment: What have you `try:`ed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can do:

```
import logging
should_abort = False

def do_stuff():
    global should_abort
    ...

def main():
    while not should_abort:  # your main loop
        try:
            do_stuff()
        except MyException1, e:
            logging.exception('GOT MyException1 %s', e)
        except MyException2, e:
            logging.exception('GOT MyException2 %s', e)
        except Exception, e:
            logging.exception('UNKNOWN EXCEPTION %s', e)
```

This still allows you to stop using ctrl-C, as `KeyboardInterrupt` derives from `BaseException`, not `Exception`.